# jqGrid doesn't show data

Tags: php, mysql, jqgrid

I can't get to load data from a database with jqgrid. I used the demo code on the wiki (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid) and it works, but when I try to load info from my own database it simply doesn't work.

I used the demo code and changed it according to the table I want to use, to see if I coded something wrong the first time, and it didn't work.

index.html:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
$("#list").jqGrid({
url:'dades.php',
datatype: 'xml',
mtype: 'GET',
colNames:['Id','Nom', 'Email','Poblacio','Naixement','Tel'],
colModel :[ 
{name:'id', index:'id', width:55}, 
{name:'nom', index:'nom', width:90}, 
{name:'email', index:'email', width:80, align:'right'}, 
{name:'poblacio', index:'poblacio', width:80, align:'right'}, 
{name:'naixement', index:'naixement', width:80, align:'right'}, 
{name:'tel', index:'tel', width:150, sortable:false} 
],
pager: '#pager',
rowNum:10,
rowList:[10,20,30],
sortname: 'id',
sortorder: 'desc',
viewrecords: true,
gridview: true,
caption: 'My first grid'
}); 
}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table> 
<div id="pager"></div> 
</body>

</html>
```

dades.php :

```
<?php 
//include the information needed for the connection to MySQL data base server. 
// we store here username, database and password 

include("dbconfig.php");

// to the url parameter are added 4 parameters as described in colModel
// we should get these parameters to construct the needed query
// Since we specify in the options of the grid that we will use a GET method 
// we should use the appropriate command to obtain the parameters. 
// In our case this is $_GET. If we specify that we want to use post 
// we should use $_POST. Maybe the better way is to use $_REQUEST, which
// contain both the GET and POST variables. For more information refer to php documentation.
// Get the requested page. By default grid sets this to 1. 
$page = $_GET['page']; 

// get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum parameter in the grid 
$limit = $_GET['rows']; 

// get index row - i.e. user click to sort. At first time sortname parameter -
// after that the index from colModel 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; 

// sorting order - at first time sortorder 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 

// if we not pass at first time index use the first column for the index or what you want
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1; 

// connect to the MySQL database server 
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error()); 

// select the database 
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error connecting to db."); 

// calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the result 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM llista"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
$count = $row['count']; 

// calculate the total pages for the query 
if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
              $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
} else { 
              $total_pages = 0; 
} 

// if for some reasons the requested page is greater than the total 
// set the requested page to total page 
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;

// calculate the starting position of the rows 
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;

// if for some reasons start position is negative set it to 0 
// typical case is that the user type 0 for the requested page 
if($start <0) $start = 0; 

// the actual query for the grid data 
$SQL = "SELECT id,nom,email,poblacio,naixement,tel FROM llista ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error()); 

// we should set the appropriate header information. Do not forget this.
header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");

$s = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
$s .=  "<rows>";
$s .= "<page>".$page."</page>";
$s .= "<total>".$total_pages."</total>";
$s .= "<records>".$count."</records>";

// be sure to put text data in CDATA
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $s .= "<row id='". $row['id']."'>";            
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['id']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['nom']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['email']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['poblacio']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['naixement']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['tel']."</cell>";
    $s .= "</row>";
}
$s .= "</rows>"; 

echo $s;
?>
```

Anybody here know why it dodn't work?

(EDIT)

For the tests I done, it seems that de problem is in the GET part:

```
$page = $_GET['page']; 

// get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum parameter in the grid 
$limit = $_GET['rows']; 

// get index row - i.e. user click to sort. At first time sortname parameter -
// after that the index from colModel 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; 

// sorting order - at first time sortorder 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 

// if we not pass at first time index use the first column for the index or what you want
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;
```

it seems that it doesn't work, but i don't understand why.

(EDIT 2)

It seems that the GET part don't work so I ended up doing without it, and the big problem was in the wrong UTF in the database...so changing the database character set and the GETs it works flawlessly.

Comment: Could you include XML data which produce your server? You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to catch data from the server HTTP response. Additionally it can be important to know the value of "Content-Type" in the HTTP header.

Comment: the header in dades.php is:
header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");

Comment: Could you include XML data which produce your server?

Answer (score 0):

for one thing, you haven't changed the result set count query.

```
 // calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the result 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM invheader");
```

you still need to update this to

```
// calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the result 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM llista");
```

also, you shouldn't need content in the html table:

```
<table id="list"></table>
```

Comment: thanks, I edit this (allways stupid mistakes are the worse to spot...) but the problems are still here.